# filebeat httpjson fails to call endpoint: failed to execute http client: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

trying to configure "Custom API" integration (aka filebeat httpjson)

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-httpjson.html

the endpoint is well known and it has a valid certificate: https://httpbin.org/get

configuration is very simple

```yaml
filebeat.inputs:
- type: httpjson
  request.method: GET
  interval: 1m
  request.url: https://httpbin.org/get
```

as a result i see following error in agent log:

```
Error while processing http request: failed to execute rf.collectResponse:
 failed to execute http client.Do: failed to read http.response.body:
 Get "https://httpbin.org/get": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

what are the options to fix or ignore the error?

all running in containers

```
docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.9.0
docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.9.0
docker.elastic.co/beats/elastic-agent:8.9.0
```

Comment: Please include information about the environment (OS, containerized?) and the Filebeat version. If it cannot verify the server's cert then that would imply that the Filebeat Go binary could not find the trusted root certs from the host.

Comment: added information

Comment: I did not get any error when replicating with Elastic Agent 8.9.0. Did you mount anything into the elastic-agent container related to /etc/ssl/certs?

Comment: Can you `curl` that url from inside the Egent container?  Does your env have some mitm proxy that's causing this issue?

Comment: thank you. my bad. curl is failing as well. company intercepting traffic... )